# Variable selection in Bayesian hierarchical models with R-INLA

Tags: bayesian, feature-selection, model-selection, hierarchical-bayesian, inla

I'm working with Bayesian hierarchichal regressions fitted with R-INLA. I would like to simplify my model by reducing the number of covariates.

According to my understanding, [Bayesian variable selection (spike & slab priors) cannot be done with R-INLA](https://groups.google.com/g/r-inla-discussion-group/c/zfQkAiaW0nQ/m/Q9YJZBtDAAAJ) . I don't like the idea of forward/backward selection based on some information criteria (WAIC, DIC).

What approaches would you recommend for variable selection in this context? I'd appreciate it if you could cite your sources.

Comment: I solved this problem (not for R-INLA, but it was Gaussian Process as well) by chosing different tool for variable selection. I used R package Boruta for this purpose, along with simple GLM with backward selection.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at the Boruta method. But I'm trying to avoid stepwise selection...

Comment: Projpred is an r library designed to help with this. Have you looked at that library?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, projpred looks interesting. However, in this case I'm looking for methods that could be compatible with INLA.